In Advanced Network Configuration Ethernet connection no device listed under Device. Network is Unclaimed
I lost my Ethernet connection and cant get it back. This was not an upgrade. It happened after an update. My system is running Ubuntu 22.04.5.
In previous versions of Ubuntu, this happened every time an update was sent out changing the RTL8111/8168/8411 to 8169. Now in 22.04.5 something is different, and the same fixes don't seem to work. On top of that I think I applied a fix by mistake that was for a WiFi card that isn't in my system. My RTL8111/8168/8411 doesn't seem to be correctly configured. In the Advanced Network Manager under the Ethernet tab no device is listed. When I run the command:
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff memory:fd600000-fd61ffff

$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel modules: r8168
04:0e.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [104c:8024]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:1000]

$ uname -a

Linux david-linux 6.8.0-48-generic #48~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  7 11:24:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How do I get the Ethernet claimed and recognized by Network Manager?
For the last week I have read and tried as many suggestions from previous posts, and they either didn't work or didn't apply. I don't have WiFi to this Desktop PC. It's a hard wired Ethernet connection. I can't find a post that addresses -network UNCLAIMED. Is that my starting point or am I way off base here? I did read that 22.04 handles networking differently than previous versions. So I may have broken Network Manager while trying to fix it. I would really appreciate any help on where to start.
I also have a list of most of the commands that I have run in the terminal if anyone would like me to list them.
I have checked the Ethernet cable and replaced it as well. Both ends have lights on but show no traffic on the link.
I have gone over my post of two years ago several times and can't seem to repeat fixing the problem. Should I be getting this result from this command?
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service

Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.

I found the following command and ran it. Now the NIC card is recognized, but the Unit network-manager.service not found.
sudo nmcli networking off && sudo nmcli networking on

david@david-linux:~$ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: 6c:f0:49:e7:27:7d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-49-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff memory:fd600000-fd61ffff

david@david-linux:~$ sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.

This problem is beyond my understanding. With my Dyslexia I just can't make any headway into a repair. So my option now is to start over with a new install and hope the next version of Ubuntu works for this RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

you need to install the drivers.  does the additional drivers tool show you any drivers to install?

No additional drivers are available. Also the software updater is  up to date.

Is r8168-dkms installed on your system?  If so install it, and reboot and see if it works.  If not I will see if I can get a newer copy for you.

'$ sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
r8168-dkms is already the newest version (8.049.02-1ubuntu1.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

When I check the network status after rebooting the network is still unclaimed.

I have gone over my post of two years ago several times and cant seem to repeat fixing the problem. Should I be getting this result from this command.   sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service    Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.
